# Why does my nodemailer stopped working with Outlook?

Tags: node.js, outlook, nodemailer

I'm working on a project using Nodemailer and Outlook for the email server. It was working well before, but now I get this error every time I trigger the sendMail function:

```
Error: Message failed: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:OutboundSpamException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message [BeginDiagnosticData]WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is Suspend, ShowTierUpgrade. OutboundSpamException: WASCL UserAction verdict is not None. Actual verdict is Suspend, ShowTierUpgrade.[EndDiagnosticData] [Hostname=VI1PR09MB3664.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com]
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Or a free alternative to Outlook?

This is my code:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "hotmail",

    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.WORD,
    },

    port: process.env.PORT_SMTP,
})

const sendMail = (to, subject, html) => {
    let mailDetails = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        html: html,
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailDetails, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return err
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent successfully.")
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks for your answers!